# Setting up DNS Records to Always Resolve to the Naked Domain (without www)

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, redirect, windows-server-2016

I am using Enom.com's DNS Servers to manage several domains' DNS settings. I'm having trouble understanding how to correctly set up the DNS so that all http requests will resolve to a naked domain without resulting in `example.com redirected you too many times` error.

So, regardless of any of the following:

```
http://www.example.com
http://foo.example.com
http://*.example.com
```

The DNS record should always redirect to the naked domain of `http://example.com`

## IIS Server (Windows 2016)

Further, I'd prefer not to set up an IIS URL Rewrite with a Canonical Domain Name rule for every domain. My preference is to have the DNS records simply resolve everything back to the naked domain.

#### IIS Host Records

My server relies heavily on Host Header Records to correctly resolve the incoming request to the correct website. In other words, several domains' A Records point to the same IP Address on my server.

#### Current DNS Record Configuration (with Enom)

```
Host Name       Record Type     Address
www             URL Redirect    example.com
@ (none)        A (Address)     1.2.3.4
* (all others)  URL Redirect    example.com
```

The URL Redirect record is a special record Enom provides.
From the [Enom Host Records help page](https://www.enom.com/help/faq_hostrecords.aspx):

> URL Redirect is not a native DNS record type. Specifying URL Redirect
> for a hostname creates an underlying A record that directs the name to
> our URL Forwarding servers. These servers then perform an HTTP 301
> redirect to the URL you specify in the address field. You can specify
> only the domain name to go to, or a full path to a specific file.

## Summary of Question

How can I set up the DNS Records so that all variants of a domain are always sent to the naked domain without having to use an IIS URL Rewrite rule?

Comment: Provide true names and IP addresses. No point in obfuscating them.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - not sure I follow? This is more of a general question; I've already provided a sample DNS configuration. I'd like to know if anyone has experience, particularly with Enom's URL Redirect DNS setting. And if the current sample config looks correct. What other information can I provide you?

Comment: Did you try to contact Enom's support? You are paying them for this service, no? Your question is not a DNS question: there is no DNS "redirect" nor URL redirect at the DNS level. This is a mix of DNS + HTTP redirections or whatever, that are provided by a specific service so the company providing it is probably your best course. A pure DNS wildcard in the `example.com` (sic) zone would indeed point all names below it to the same IP addresses, and there a webserver has to handle all requests.

Comment: Fair enough. I have submitted a support ticket to Enom.

Answer (score 1):

DNS cant redirect users. You have to configure your webserver (iis in this case) to redirect (301) users that type www.domain.tld to domain.tld. DNS only resolves names... You can setup a "redirect virtual host" that is a catch-all to redirect users to your main site (google "wildcard subdomain"). I've done this with apache (except the other way around, i wanted the www... I'm old fashioned)

Comment: What about in the context of my question where Enom provides a DNS URL-Redirect?

Comment: My bad, reading up on it now... I've never used it...

Comment: Unless they support wildcards, the only way i could imagine this would work is to use iis. 2016 supports wildcard virtual hosts. Personally i would rather redirect myself... I'm odd like that..

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the wildcard subdomain; I'll likely end up with something similar if this simply isn't supported by Enom's DNS servers.